# Mips32 printing a string that is stores on the stack

Tags: mips, code-generation

I push each character on the stack and I call print_s function:
The output is **h** instead of **hel**

```
sub $sp, $sp, 4
li $t9, 'h'
sb $t9, 0($sp)
li $t9, 'e'
sb $t9, -1($sp)
li $t9, 'l'
sb $t9, -2($sp)
li $t9, 0      #tried $zero, '0' '\0'
sb $t9, -3($sp)
la $a0, 0($sp)
jal print_s
#code that exits here.
print_s:
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

Any ideas why it doesn't print the string ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

the reason that this code did not work is because the stack grows downwards(e.g addresses go from high to low. The correct way is to store the string in the opposite order:

```
sub $sp, $sp, 4
li $t9, '\0'
sb $t9, 0($sp)
li $t9, 'l'
sb $t9, -1($sp)
li $t9, 'e'
sb $t9, -2($sp)
li $t9, 'h'
sb $t9, -3($sp)
la $a0, -3($sp)
jal print_s
#code that exits here.
print_s:
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    jr $ra
```